# Two functions with the same name inside the same page

Tags: javascript, function

I'd like to ask if it is possible in javascript to insert two functions with the same name in the same page.

For example, I've crated a script anyone can use in their website, this script just contains:

```
function sayHello(){
 alert("Hello World")
}
```

Now let's say that the same user would like to add another script, but changing the alert messagge, so at the end it would be something like this:

```
function sayHello(){
 alert("Hello World");
}

function sayHello(){
 alert("How are you?");
}
```

The script would return just "How are you".

So, is there another way to make javascript executes two functions with the same name?
If not, is it possible to fix it in a way that doesn't obliges the final user to change manually the function's name?

Comment: Do you want both functions, or just the second one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fix is to put the two bodies together:

```
function sayHello(){
 alert("Hello World");
 alert("How are you?");
}
```

If you need a programmatic way of doing this, use an array. Simple:

```
var messages = ["Hello World", "How are you?"];
function sayHello(){
 for (var i=0; i<messages.length; i++) 
  alert(messages[i]);
}
```

Complex:

```
var functions = [
 // function expressions even can use the same name (which is local)
 // without overwriting each other
 function sayHello(){
  alert("Hello World");
 },
 function sayHello(){
  alert("How are you?");
 }
];
function sayHello(){
 for (var i=0; i<functions.length; i++)
  functions[i].call();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive reply! I'll take a look at your code.